# Flutter how to access the map from Future Function

Tags: dictionary, flutter, dart, future

New to dart, I want to access the value `userId` inside the `Map` object, but I keep getting an Error (See comment):

```
The method 'then' isn't defined for the type 'Function'.
Try correcting the name to the name of an existing method, or defining a method named 'then'.
```

```
  Future<Map> getData() async {
    Response load = await get('https://jsonplaceholder.typicode.com/todos/1');
    print(load.statusCode);
    print(load.body);
    Map map = jsonDecode(load.body);
    return map;
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    var getit = getData;
    print('placeholder');
    getit.then((e){e['userId'];}); // I get an Error here
    super.initState();
  }
```

Comment: Remove the getit variable and use this `getData().then( (response) { response['userId'];  } ) `

Comment: The way you have it, you're assigning the FUNCTION named getData to the variable getit. You didn't *call* the function. To fix this, you can simply change the line to be like this `var getit = getData();`

Comment: @loganrussell48 and PrasannaKumar, thank you guys I feel a bit stupid now. Much appreciated.
Please post this as an answer so I can check it as answered.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issues arise from the line `var getit = getData;`

When you provide the method name with no parenthesis(`getData`), you're passing the method as an object rather than calling the method and retrieving its return value.

To fix the issue, simply call the method by providing parenthesis:

`var getit = getData();`